# Keras CNN get output from the Convolutional steps

Tags: python, keras, convolution

I am beginning to build CNN models using Keras.

I have built a CNN with a fairly accurate results using the following architecture.

```
classifier = Sequential()


classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))


classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.25))
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.25))


classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What I want to do is to run my images through the model, but only the convolutional steps. I am interested in the output of the Flattening process (i.e. get the features from the convolutional steps).

Can someone help me how I can get it in Keras?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. If you are interested in the output of layer `'max_pooling2d_4'` (You can get the layer name by `classifier.summary()`, but I suggest you to put names for each layer by e.g. `classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), name='pool1'))`):

```
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in classifier.layers])

# input tensor
input_tensor = classifier.input

# output tensor of the given layer
layer_output = layer_dict['max_pooling2d_4'].output

# get the output with respect to the input
func = K.function([input_tensor], [layer_output])

# test image: [64, 64, 3]
image = np.ones((64,64,3))

# get activation for the test image
activation = func([image[np.newaxis, :, :, :]])
```